A "new" lemma regarding an equation of an arbitrary function $φ: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$
Lemma. Consider a function  $\phi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, a positive integer $m$ and suppose that there exists functions $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ and $g:A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb N$ so that:

$f(n) \leq \phi (n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$,
$g$ is increasing,
and $f(\mathbb N) \subseteq A$ so that $g \circ f=id_{\mathbb N \to \mathbb N}$.

Then the equation $\phi (x)=m$ $(\ast)$ has finitely many solutions over $\mathbb N$.
Proof. Consider $\cal L_m \subseteq \mathbb N$ the set of all solutions of $(\ast)$ and assume by way of contradiction that $\cal L_m$ is infinite. Now, take $x \in \cal L_m$. Thus, $f(x) \leq \phi (x)=m$, and so $1 \leq x=g(f(x)) \leq g(m)$. Therefore, $\cal L_m$ is bounded, impossible, q.e.d.
Now, my question is whether this trivial result has already been discovered. Lastly, I'd like to present some examples of this lemma.
Example 1 Consider $φ$ to be the Euler totient function. It is true that $φ(n) \ge \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ for all positive integers $n$, and so the equation $φ(x)=m$ has finitely many solutions for all positive integers $m$.
Example 2 If $\sigma_1$ is the sum of divisors function, then $\sigma_1 (n) \ge n-1$ for all positive integers, and so a similar result follows.
Comment The difficult part is finding an appropriate function $f$, as seen in example 1.

It's clear that $\varphi (n)$ and $\sigma_1(n)$ take any given value at most finitely often.

What I suggest:  to show that this is a useful tool, find some function for what the desired claim isn't easily established by other means.  Otherwise, it seems like a rather complicated way to demonstrate something simple.

@lulu My mathematical knowledge is quite restricted, since I am only a first a year undergrad, but I could play around with this and in parallel try some known arithmetic functions. Of course anyone can, and they could freely comment on this post.

@lulu Simplifying proofs of known results would suffice to demonstrate the usefulness of the lemma.
